# Appcompat and Facebook libraries conflict?

Tags: android, facebook, android-appcompat

I have some trouble to use the Facebook SDK. In my app I use the Appcompat library for the actionbar and other stuff. When I'm now trying to include the Facebook SDK library like shown in the image below, my project suddenly gets errors everywhere.
[image: Valid XHTML]
<sub>(source: [fiedlers.info](http://fiedlers.info/Unbenannt.png))</sub>

Basically it seems like the Appcompat library is not included anymore, activities that don't use Appcompat don't have any problems.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: have you tried level up the AppCompact in the Project Build path?

Comment: Facebook library uses appcompat v4. Try adding it to your facebook library.

Comment: if u have Duplicate jar files replace the Appcompact that you use inside the Facebook SDK folder

Comment: So that's where I think I lack some understanding. AppCompact is not listed in "Order and Export". I basically don't get the difference between adding a library under "Android->Library" like shown above and adding a JAR to the Java Build Path. When is which action required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Itzik Samara said the problem was, that the AppCompact library was included twice, once in its own project folder and once as part of the Facebook SDK. These two files need to have the same MD5 hash, meaning have to be exactly the same. So I just copied the appcompat v7 file from the Appcompat project and overwrote the file in the libs folder of the Facebook SDK.

Comment: If Facebook already included Appcompat library, couldn't you just remove it from your own project and everything else would be ok right?